# Как вызвать img.src - синхронно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть масив из ссылок изображений .
после я проверяю на то что изображения ли это и вывожу на странице.

```
let images = ["http://site.com/photo.png" , "http://site.com/somelink.html" , "http://site.com/photo.png"];
let images_filter = [];

for(let i =0 ; i < images.length;i++){
   let image = new Image();
   image.src = images[i];
   image.onload = function(){
      images_filter.push(image.src);
   };
}
```

cкрипт работает но работает асинхронно и в итоге сортировка которая была сделана до этого просто пропадает , как запустить скрипт синхронно ?

Comment: img.src это не функция, это в принципе невозможно как-либо вызвать

Comment: "как запустить скрипт синхронно ?" - никак

Comment: можно проверить по другому ссылку ?

Comment: Синхронно - никак. Учитесь делать правильно асинхронно

Answer (score 1):

Можно обернуть загрузку в Promise

```js
async function whenImage(image){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const isLoaded = image.complete;
  if (isLoaded)
    resolve(image);

  image.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(image), {once: true})
  image.addEventListener("error", reject, {once: true})

})
}
```

С помощью ключевого слова await вы заставляете интерпретатор ждать выполнения Обещания (Promise). То есть загрузки изображения.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

```js
await whenImage()
```

```js
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
   const image = new Image();
   image.src = images[i];
   await whenImage(image);

   images_filter.push(image.src);
}
```

Однако загрузка изображений может происходить быстрее, если она асинхронная. Возможно, лучше переделать?

Comment: у меня есть масив ссылок которых я проверяю на изображения , мне надо сделать функцию проверки всех ссылок а после сделать return массива с ссылками которые прошли проверку , как мне это сделать ?

Comment: С помощью Promise.all можно дождаться загрузки всех изображений, а после отфильтровать те, которые завершились ошибкой

Comment: const images = imagesURL.map(url => {const image = new Image(); image.src = url; return whenImage(image)); const results = await Promise.allSettled(images); console.iog(results)